# How to give post.map in container as children to parent in react native

Tags: react-native

i have a problem to wrapping for post.map , i already tried so so many times to wrapper in render function . because i want to get data by id form detail user. sorry iam newbie in react native.

i already try to give Tag view, but the touchable menu cant be click, i already tried to search in stackoverflow but nothing . i need your help guys to fix my newbie problem

```js
 onLogoutPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Logout')
 }

 onTransaction = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Transaction')
 }

 onPostMap = () => {
    const {post} = this.state;
    {post.map (post => (a))}
 }

 render() {
    return ( <View>
                <DashboardComponent 
                    onLogoutPress={this.onLogoutPress}
                    onTransaction={this.onTransaction}
                />

            {
                this.state.post.map(post => {
                    return <DashboardComponent key= {post.id} data = {post} />
                })
            }
            </View>
        );
 }
```

dashboard component

```js
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.profileFieldButtonStyle}>
    <Image style={styles.profileFieldTextStyle} source={email} resizeMode={'contain'}/>
    <Text style={{marginLeft: '7%'}}>love3000@gmail.com</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

i expect that "love3000@gmail.com" become props.data.email . i hope you can help me @.@. thank you before

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem more?.What is the expected output and what is your current state.

Comment: look it at the bottom off the code. i expect "love3000@gmail.com" become props.data.email that get from json data

Comment: does the below answer works for you?.

Comment: not work. nothing was returned from render, wrong on dashboard container,

Answer (score 0):

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.profileFieldButtonStyle}>
   <Image style={styles.profileFieldTextStyle} source={email} resizeMode={'contain'}/>
   <Text style={{marginLeft: '7%'}}>{this.props.data.email}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```